# How to Select all Highlights of a certain color in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

I need to select all green highlights in a .docx file at one time. I presume it's necessary a macro, but i don't know how to compile it. Can someone help me with this?

I found this code, but it deletes all highlights after have found them, while i only need them to be selected:

```
    Sub Highlight()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveDocument.Range

With r.Find
.Highlight = True
Do While .Execute(FindText:="", Forward:=True) = True
If r.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen Then
r.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto
r.Collapse 0
End If
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: replace `r.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto
r.Collapse 0` by`r.select`

Comment: to Dorian: this only selects the last highlight of the document, while i need to select all green highlights of it

Comment: what do you want to do exactly

Comment: to select all green highlighted texts of the document at one time

Comment: in order to do what ?

Comment: In order to handle them in many ways: change color, copying, deleting...

Comment: I think that you will have to modify your stuff directly in your loop

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different color indexes in the VBA world.  You need to define the exact green that you want to work with.  This may be a good place to start.

```
Sub DeleteYellowHighlight()
Dim rDcm As Range
Set rDcm = ActiveDocument.Range
With rDcm.Find
    .Highlight = True
While .Execute
If rDcm.Font.ColorIndex = 4 Then
    rDcm.Select
End If
Wend
End With
End Sub
```

Or...

```
Sub FindNextYellow()
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Highlight = True
    Do
        .Execute
    Loop Until Selection.Range.Font.ColorIndex = 4 _
      Or Not .Found
    Selection.Range.Select
End With
End Sub
```

Also, see this link for some ideas of what you can do and where you can go with this kind of thing.

https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/colors

Comment: Yes, run it in Word.  When your Word document is open, hit ALT+F11 (simultaneously) to see the VBA window; click Insert > Module.  Paste your code into that window.  Hit F8 to step through the code one line at a time; hit F5 to run the code.